# Showing that $\|f-g\|_{L^1}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mu\left[\left(F(t) \setminus G(t)\right) \cup \left(G(t) \setminus F(t)\right)\right] \,dt.$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $f,g$ be measurable and integrable functions on a measure space $(X, \mu)$ and let us define the following sets,
$$F(t)=\{x\in X: f(x)> t\}\quad G(t)=\{x\in X: g(x)> t\}.$$
I would like to show that
$$\|f-g\|_{L^1}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mu\left[\left(F(t) \setminus G(t)\right) \cup \left(G(t) \setminus F(t)\right)\right] \,dt.$$

I first thought of trying to use the same technique to show that
$$\|f\|_{L^1}=\int_X|f|\,dx=\int_X\int_0^\infty 1_{t<|f|}\,dt\,dx=\int_0^\infty\mu\{x\in X: |f|>t\},$$
but got quickly got stuck trying to break down $|f-g|>t$ into cases.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the hypothesis of Fubini's theorem are fulfilled,
$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mu\left(F(t) \setminus G(t)\right)\,dt&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mu\left(\{x\mid f(x)>t\ge g(x)\right)\,dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_X1_{f>t\ge g}(x)d\mu(x)\right)\,dt\\&=\int_X 1_{f>g}(f-g)d\mu.
\end{align}$$
Similarly,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mu\left(G(t) \setminus F(t)\right)\,dt=\int_X 1_{g>f}(g-f)d\mu,$$
whence the result.